# How to install global isapi filters with wix? (IIS 7.5)

Tags: wix, iis-7.5, isapi

I am struggling to install a com based isapi dll globally into iis 7.5 using wix 3.6.3303.1/4.0.12.0.

I have the following wix config ([full config here](https://gist.github.com/4319729)):

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="IsapiDll" Guid="ADD-GUID-HERE">
      <File Id="isapidll" Name="isapi.dll" Source="isapi.dll" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="IisFilter" Guid="ADD-GUID-HERE">
      <CreateFolder />
      <iis:WebFilter Id="IisFilter" Name="MyIsapi" Path="[INSTALLFOLDER]isapi.dll" LoadOrder="last" Description="MyIsapi" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

I receive the following error in my msi log when running on Windows 7 32bit with IIS7.5:

```
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x8007000e: Failed while finding IAppHostElement filter/@name=(null)
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x8007000e: Failed to delete filter
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x8000ffff: Unexpected IIS Config action specified for global filter
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to configure IIS filter global.
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x8000ffff: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
```

I fear the problem is a bug in wix itself.
[CreateGlobalFilter()](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62deafa7b2a4#src/ca/serverca/scaexec/scaexecIIS7.cpp) passes pwzFilterName to DeleteCollectionElement() before it has been assigned a value. This later causes [Iis7FindAppHostElementString()](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62deafa7b2a4#src/dutil/iis7util.cpp) to be called with a null wzAttributeValue value which appears to be the cause of the error.

I could of course be on a wild goose chase and be happy to be pointed in the right direction...

Update:
I've now played with website level installs and have that working with the addition of the WebSite attribute and  element. [Config here](https://gist.github.com/4329216)

Edit: Changed path attribute to correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x8007000e` means out of memory and the `(null)` in the message makes me bet this is a bug in the custom action. If you can debug it that's ideal. In any case, entering a bug at http://wixtoolset.org/bugs would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Rob, i'll file a bug and have a look into debugging if/when i get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add WebSite attribute, this code works well for me in WIX3.7:

```
<Component Id="IsapiFilterComponent" Guid="AE102719-D7DE-450A-A44C-29E7D9A36C0D" KeyPath="yes">
  <iis:WebFilter Id="MyWebDavFilter" Name="MyWebDavFilter" Path="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyWebDavFilter.dll" LoadOrder="last" Description="My Web Dav Filter" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" />
</Component>
```

but this

```
<Component Id="IsapiFilterComponent" Guid="AE102719-D7DE-450A-A44C-29E7D9A36C0D" KeyPath="yes">
  <iis:WebFilter Id="MyWebDavFilter" Name="MyWebDavFilter" Path="INSTALLFOLDER]MyWebDavFilter.dll" LoadOrder="last" Description="My Web Dav Filter"/>
</Component>
```

gives the same error you have.

Of course, you have to add `<iis:WebSite>` element to your wxs file.

Comment: Hi, this installs a site specific isapi filter which works for me too. I unfortunately need a global filter.